# Python Loop through emails in outlook

Tags: python, outlook, email-attachments, win32com, office-automation

This code takes email pdf attachments, download it, merge to one pdf file and send further.

Now it takes all emails which are marked with specific category in that inbox, so it merge all pdf's from all emails to one file.

But I want that it take emails one by one, that after download pdf's from one email it will merge and send them, delete them from folder and just after that it will take second email.

How to make such loop for this code?

```
  import datetime
  import os
  import win32com.client as win32
  from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger
  from pathlib import Path

  path = ('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work')
  today = datetime.date.today()

  outlook = win32.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
  inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
  subFolder = inbox.Folders("Test")
  messages = subFolder.Items


  def save_attachments(subject):
     for message in messages:
       if message.Categories == "Red Category":
         for attachment in message.Attachments:
            print(attachment.FileName)

            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))


     if __name__ == "__main__":
     save_attachments('PB report - next steps')

     #Merge PDF's

     merger = PdfFileMerger()

     path_to_files = r'C:\Users\Desktop\Work/'

    for root, dirs, file_names in os.walk(path_to_files):

    for file_name in file_names:
    
    merger.append(path_to_files + file_name)

    merger.write(r"C:\Users\Desktop\Work\merged.pdf")
    merger.close()

    #Send PDF with outlook

   # construct Outlook application instance
   olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
   olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

  # construct the email item object
  mailItem = olApp.CreateItem(0)
  mailItem.Subject = 'Test'
  mailItem.BodyFormat = 1
  mailItem.Body = "Pdf merged"
  mailItem.To = 'email' 
  path = (os.path.join('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work\\merged.pdf'))

 mailItem.Attachments.Add(path)
 mailItem.Display()
 mailItem.Save()
 mailItem.Send()

 #Delete PDF's from folder

 [f.unlink() for f in Path("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\Work").glob("*") if f.is_file()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over all items in the folder is not really a good idea:

```
  for message in messages:
       if message.Categories == "Red Category":
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class from the Outlook object model. So, in that case you will get all items that correspond to your search criteria and iterate over them only. Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Second, there is no need to create a new Outlook `Application` instance:

```
 # construct Outlook application instance
   olApp = win32.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')
   olNS = olApp.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
```

Re-use the existing application instance instead. Moreover, Outlook is a singleton, you can't have two instances running at the same time.

Third, there is no need to display and save the item created before sending:

```
mailItem.Attachments.Add(path)
mailItem.Send()
```

Comment: But I need solution which let me to go through those emails one by one , not that it take all emails with that category on the same time and download everything.